# Model property is set to null by thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have been dealing with the following issue:

I have a simple model class called User.

```cs
public class User{

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  ...}
```

And this is my the controller code:

```cs
@RequestMapping ( value = "/users", params = { "id" } )
public String showEditForm( final Model model, final HttpServletRequest req )
{
    User edit = this.userRepository.findOne( Long.valueOf( req.getParameter( "id" ) ) );
    model.addAttribute( "user", edit );
    return "edit-user";
}


@RequestMapping ( value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"edit"     
}) 
public String editUser( @Valid @ModelAttribute ( "user" ) final User user,
final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model )
{
   if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() )
    {
        return "edit-user";
    }

    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

The following is the code snippet to displaying all the users:

```html
<div class="userlist" th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(users)}">
    <h2 th:text="#{list.user.title}"></h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th th:text="#{name}" />
                <th th:text="#{details}" />                 
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="u : ${users}">
                <td th:text="${u.name}" />                  
                <td><a th:href="@{/users(id=${tc.id})}" th:text="#{edit}"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And eventually the submit form:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/users}" th:object="${user}"
        method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" class="errorlist">
                <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="name"> <span th:text="#{name}"></span>
                </label> <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
                    th:class=" ${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'fieldError'" />
            </div>          
            <div class="submit">
                <button type="submit" th:text="#{update}" name="edit"></button>                 
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And now the problem description:
As long as the 'id'-field is present within the submit form, everything works fine. If I remove the 'id'-field from the submit form though, because the id property isn't meant to be modified, the workflow doesn't work anymore. In fact, the id is null in the editUser() method. I assume that Thymeleaf does set the value of the id property to null if it is not present within the submit form. But I'm not sure about this. And I think there must be some solution to this problem other than having to let the id-property reside in the submit form.

I hope anyone can help here out.

Thanks.

Edmond

Comment: In 2018:
Check the manual, Chapter 6
http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc Or Tutorial 7.2
https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form Just use th:object in the form and use th:field="*{xxx}" in your input/textarea/... [codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSB8C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id field should be present in form otherwise how controller would know which user should be updated.

If this field is meaningless for client (that is it's some generated unique id) it should be done hidden. If it may be of some interest for client this field can be done read-only.

Comment: You should avoid, as much as possible, the exposing of technical keys/ids in your screen. If I'm a malicious user, I could change the id and modify a whole different user. So from a security point-of-view that isn't a wise thing to do.

Comment: M.Deinum - yes, but that's why form should be validated on server side (for ex. using BindingResult)

Answer (score 11):

That has nothing to do with Thymeleaf, but how binding works. Spring will only bind attributes to the model object which are present as parameter in the request. If you remove id that isn't present and as such cannot be bound (what should it be bound to?).

A solution to this is to either specify the id as a hidden form, so that it is present. Or in between requests store your object in the session (using `@SessionAttributes` on the controller) that way the earlier retrieved object is going to be used for binding.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User initUser(@RequestParam("id") Long id) {
        return this.userRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    RequestMapping ( value = "/users", params = { "id" } )
    public String showEditForm() {
        return "edit-user";
    }

    @RequestMapping ( value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"edit"}) 
    public String editUser( @Valid @ModelAttribute ( "user" ) final User user, final BindingResult bindingResult, SessionStatus status;) {
       if ( bindingResult.hasErrors() ) {
            return "edit-user";
        }
        status.setComplete(); // Indicate we are done,so @SessionAttributes can be cleaned up
        return "redirect:/users";
    }
```

Something like that should preserve the User between sessions, and the `SessionStatus` can then be used to trigger the cleanup of the session attributes.

Comment: Thanks, adding ```@SessionAttributes()``` helped me storing hidden properties of my object like ID, etc, on the session, so I don't have to publish it in the form. I was concerned about security